# Retrieve "managed" flag of router advertisement from build-in IPv6 SLAAC support

Tags: kernel, ipv6, router, netlink

The linux kernel has support for IPv6 SLAAC (stateless address auto-configuration) and is able to process received router advertisement messages.

**BUT:** As much as I can understand, the kernel is not processing two things of the router advertisement:

1. 'M'/'O' flag to indicate the existence of a DHCPv6 server in the network *(this is stored in the inet6_dev, but never used)*
2. DNS option to pass a DNS server in the RA *(this is ignored completely)*

**Is there a way to retrieve this information from the userspace?**

Comment: the rdisc6 command uses raw sockets to receive the M/O information. the rdnssd command uses a netlink  option specific to the DNS parameter. You could study these two commands (and their sources) to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seams like there is no way to retrieve this information from the kernel via netlink**

## But

I figured out way to retrieve this information through another way thanks to user A.B

I used a raw socket that only listens to icmpv6-router-advertisement messages. This will retrieve the exact same messages as the will kernel.

For example code I recommend you to take a look at the rdnss/icmp.c file in the ndisc6 project as A.B mentioned.
https://github.com/nomis/ndisc6/blob/master/rdnss/icmp.c